# Schengen Visa from Italian embassy

Tags: air-travel, schengen

I got a single-entry Schengen visa from Italian embassy. Now I am planning to visit first Rome after that from Rome to Paris by plane. So can I travel to Paris by plane from Rome, will immigration ask me something? Or can I travel by train only?

Comment: You should not encounter immigration when flying from Italy to France.  Even if you do, it's fine, since when you travel between those countries, you do not "enter" the Schengen area.  (This doesn't apply if you are flying through London, however; you must fly entirely within the Schengen area if you have a single-entry visa.)  But this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Going from Rome to Paris is an *internal* Schengen flight, you are not going to leave and re-enter.

However, it sounds as if you changed your itinerary after the the visa was granted. This could become a problem when it is detected, e.g. if you leave the Schengen area from France.

Comment: Itinerary changes are not forbidden.  It would only become a problem if it raises suspicion that the visa application was fraudulent.

Comment: He actually did go to Italy. I once too a flight between countries which neither of them issues the visa. There were no immigration check points and airline staff couldn't care less.

Comment: @AyeshK, that's the way Schengen is supposed to work. As phoog points out, the problem could come any time an immigration official thinks there was deception. If someone on the way from Italy to Germany decides to go through France rather than through Switzerland, that might be a minor detail if the detour takes him through Cote d'Azur and Auvergne. Showing up in the Bretange would not be minor any more.